# Can't catch scroll event IONIC V3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3

I can't seem to catch the scroll event from an ion content in Ionic 3.
I need for every scroll in a div element, to catch the scroll event to perform some calculations related.

I've tried several ways, including binding the EventEmitter (ionScroll) to a method in the HTML file, or declaring the ion-content as a viewchild and trying to subscribe it in the ngAfterViewInit() method, but none of them worked.

The method I want to bind is simple:

```js
 scrolling(event) {
   console.log(event);
 }
```

HTML File:

```
<ion-content    style="height: 20000px;" (ionScroll)="scrolling($event)" >
</ion-content>
```

Worth mention this is a component inside the home.html page from the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Content} from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class ProjectPage {
    @ViewChild(Content) content:Content;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.content.addScrollListener((event) =>  {
           //on scroll fire
       });
    }

}
```